# EMC issues for BLE certifcation

Tags: emc, bluetooth-low-energy

We have two different products but identical when it comes to the BLE SoC layout and almost identical otherwise besides an extra MCU on one of the products, which is on the bottom layer of the board. The board shape, power supply, miscellaneous components, and connectors are the same.
The product with the extra MCU is passing the FCC test requirements with flying colors. The one without isn't

The problem lies within the third harmonic being about 10dB higher than the that of the product that is passing.
We have a 6 layer pcb with stack up (signal gnd gnd gnd gnd signal).
The SoC is on an external module which has shielding.
We have removed some bypass caps and cut a trace so the stub if any is closer to the pad to minimize any ground loops. This resulted in minimal to no improvement

We have removed an opamp with a bandwidth of less than 1MHz, and as expected no improvement.

The only outstanding difference is manufacturer.
It is important to note that we have another product that uses the same SoC module and layout which also performed about the same to the passing product.

Is it possible the manufacturing quality could cause such a drastic difference, or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Is that a typo? 4 gnd layers? For decent answers, we have to be able to see the PCB layout.

Comment: If you have 4 internal GND layers and 2 signal layers on the external layers of your PCB, I have a lot of questions for your PCB layout person. What about your power layers? Have you impedance matched the correct lines? As Erik Friesen says, we need to see the layout to give a real answer. But if you have the traces going to a not fitted MCU, they would be acting as antenna, and could be the cause.